# Is it possible to have expandable tabs in your sidebar for your pages in streamlit?

Tags: sidebar, streamlit

I am trying to build a streamlit application. I have different pages in my application inside the pages folder. I have subpages for those pages. I looked at some docs about multipage application in streamlit and named the pages in the following way.:

```
 - pages
   - 0_PAGE1.py
   - 1_PAGE2.py
      - 3_ •Subpage1.py
      - 4_ •Subpage2.py
   - 5_PAGE3.py
...and so on...
```

The pages are shown in the sidebar correctly. But I want the main pages to be able to expand and unexpand and revealing and hiding the subpages in the process.
Basically, I want something like this:
[image]
Is it possible in streamlit?